# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a thinner thickness of hardwood for stairing/flooring?

Tags: flooring, engineered-flooring

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a thinner thickness of hardwood for stairing/flooring?

We are considering getting hardwood stairs as a replacement for carpet stairs and we found wood with varying amounts of thickness.   Is there a difference between a "thin" thickness and thick thickness?  Does it affect anything towards how long the wood will last, etc?

Comment: Advanfage: cheaper. Disadvantage: everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most stair treads are a true 1" thick also known as 5/4" milled. Anything less than that might sag when you walk on them depending on how it's framed. You can use 3/4" thick boards for the risers.

Flooring can be all sizes for thickness depending on the application and manufacturer because you have a subfloor to attach it to. Thinner floors make transitions from a room with the flooring to a room without it a little less drastic.